# How do I check many Individuals shared a link in facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-fql, facebook-sharer

I am new in facebook api and I am trying to check how many people shared a link. There is of course the facebook api (http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://www.techradar.com/news/phone-and-communications/mobile-phones/microsoft-officially-dumps-nokia-in-favour-of-lumia-1270035?)  but one man can just share hundreds times the same site. So does there is a way to find how many DIFFRENT people shared the link? (maybe by id)

Answer (score 0):

You can track when user shared something with a callback function, but if subsequent sharing of original share action occur I dont think you can track that part. You of course can track referrals if your share url includes that.